# How to keep ssh connection on mac?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ssh

I am trying to connect to a remote server and do some mysql queries through JDBC. But I get 'broken pipe' if I am away for some time. I wonder if I can keep connection.

Comment: What's this got to do with SSH?  Are you tunneling over SSH?

Comment: @GregKopff, I use ssh to connect the remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute a dummy query at regular interval to keep the connection alive,
MySQL drops connection at 8 hour if it stays idle (by default)

You can handle this by using connection-pooling configured such a way to execute validate-query at some interval

Comment: Any way I can modify this '8 hour'?

Comment: Not sure about modifying this 8 h, but you could handle it in Java , See updates

Comment: The problem is that I have some queries that each of them may take more than 8 hours. And also, I am required to record the execution time of the query(which means, I think, I cannot take advantage of multithreading).

Comment: I've found how to set this '8 h':http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout